# couln't get response of webpage in requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, lxml

I am trying to make a bot for my college website. In that website verification is done in two stages in 1st stage only username and in 2nd step only password is needed. But for out purpose we can directly go on password page because username gets embeded in url. This is the link http://mydy.dypatil.edu/rait/login/index.php?uname=san.yad.rt15@rait.ac.in&wantsurl=.

Following is the my code.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "http://mydy.dypatil.edu/rait/login/index.php?uname=san.yad.rt15@rait.ac.in&wantsurl="
result = session_requests.get(login_url)
form_data = {
    "uname_static": "san.yad.rt15@rait.ac.in",
    "username": "san.yad.rt15@rait.ac.in",
    "uname": "san.yad.rt15@rait.ac.in",
    "password": "dypatil@123"
}

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data=form_data,
    headers=dict(referer=login_url)
)
url = "http://mydy.dypatil.edu/rait/my/"
result = session_requests.get(
    url,
    headers = {"Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0",
    "Connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "Content-Language": "en",
    "Content-Length": "427",
    "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
    "Keep-Alive": "timeout=5, max=98",
    "Location": "http://mydy.dypatil.edu/rait/",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Server": "Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16",
    "X-Powered-By": "PHP/5.4.16"}
)
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
print(tree.text)
# subjects = tree.xpath('//*[@class="launchbutton"/@href]')
#
# for subject in subjects:
#     print(subject)
```

This does not show any error. Also when i check status code it shows 200 Ok. But in reponse `print(tree.text)` it shows couple of bank line. Can you correct me anywhere..

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
print(tree.text)
```

to this

```
print(html.tostring(tree))
```

**OR**

to get some data out:

```
from lxml import etree

for elem in tree.xpath("//div[@class='name']"):
     print etree.tostring(elem, pretty_print=True)
```

returns

```
b'<div class="name">sharad Jadhav</div>\n'
b'<div class="name">Admin User</div>\n'
b'<div class="name">sharad Jadhav</div>\n'
```

Comment: from html.tostring() now i can see the response web page. but the table which contains buttons is not visible i.e. response does not contain full web page.

Comment: That is a different question, and what you included in this comment has nowhere near the amount of info required to attempt to answer.